# How to get object from .Min extension method?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple struct:

```
public struct Coord
{
    public Coord (int Row, int Column )
    { /* set values */ }

    public int Row { get; }
    public int Column { get; }
}
```

Given:

```
int [ , ] myArray;
IEnumerable<Coord> myCoords;
```

I want to select the coordinate with the smallest value and return that coordinate.
I can get the smallest value with:

```
int val = myCoords.Min(c => myArray[c.Row, c.Col]);
```

How can I get 'Coord' returned instead?

Comment: What do you consider the smallest coordinate?

Comment: How do you define min of a `Coord`?

Comment: Define smallest coordinate? (100,1) vs (1,100) which is smaller? Or are they the same?

Comment: @Erno @Tomas @leppie: Given the code we've got, we're looking for the coordinate whose corresponding value in the `myArray` array is smallest.

Comment: @leppie: I think you're missing the point of what the OP is trying to do. "I want to select the coordinate with the smallest value" - given the sample code, that's clearly "the smallest value within the array at the given coordinates".

Comment: @JonSkeet: Seeing what is going on now :) Most confusing question of the day, 3 deleted answers already!

Comment: @leppie: Interesting - I didn't find it terribly confusing. Then again, I've lamented the lack of MinBy before, so I was already half way there...

Comment: @leppie: from my perspective it isn't confusing - but then again, I know what I mean. ;)  What will make this question less confusing? I will gladly edit to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this very easily in plain LINQ to Objects, unfortunately. You could find the minimum value and *then* find the `Coord` which has that value, but obviously that means going over the data twice.

I have a [`MinBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs) method in [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) which you could use though:

```
Coord minCoord = myCoords.MinBy(c => myArray[c.Row, c.Col]);
```

Comment: I liked the idea source.ThrowIfNull("source");

Answer (score 0):

Another less than elegant answer:

```
coords.Single( x => array[x.Row, x.Col] == coords.Min(y => array[y.Row,y.Col]));
```

Comment: `coords.Min(y => array[y.Row,y.Col])` should be cached if dealing with sizable lists.